# Getting Database is locked error

Tags: deadlock, sqlite

I have a query in which I am updating a table and have used `IN` keyword in the query. The query is something like this:

```
UPDATE q 
SET b_id = 123     
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM q WHERE b_id IS NULL LIMIT 1)
```

There is another query in which I am inserting data in table. The query is:

```
INSERT INTO q (id, item) VALUES (@id, @item)
```

The queries are executing on different threads. While executing the second (`INSERT`) query I am getting database is locked error.

What is the reason?

`id` is not primary key.

Comment: Please edit your question. Add table's DDL and real queries texts (you can simplify them by removing the fields unnesessary for the question). And remove unproper DBMS tag.

Comment: *The query is something like this* It is EXTREMELY strange. 1) subquery selects random record; 2) main query updates random record with selected random `id` (maybe the record where `b_id` is not null, if `id` is not unique).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Software Uses SQLite and Has Frequent DB Lock Errors. Zero Access to Code. Anything we can do?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/223754/software-uses-sqlite-and-has-frequent-db-lock-errors-zero-access-to-code-anyth)